# Triggering Lambda when a device Shadow updates

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-iot

I've set up a rule

```
SELECT * FROM '$aws/things/+/shadow/update/accepted'
```

This rule triggers my lambda function when the shadow of any thing in my AWS IoT updates.

Instead I want it to get triggered only when the shadows of some things are updated, not all of them. Any way I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

I recently learned that you can use functions to filter on parts of the topic, and something like this could potentially work for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM '$aws/things/+/shadow/update/accepted'
WHERE startswith(topic(3), 'someprefix-')
```

This would only trigger the action(s) when the part of the topic captured by the `+` started with "someprefix-". You can use other functions to filter in other ways if a prefix does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Each individual device you have registered will have a specific /shadow/update/accepted topic that you can subscribe to. It should be easy as replacing the '+' in your topic with the name of the device.

The same topic is also listed in the 'Interact' section of each device in IoT Core.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although as you can see above my rule already has the '+' sign in the SQL reference. It triggers my Lambda whenever any device on my AWS IoT gets updated. I want the same to happen except only for some devices in my AWS IoT, not all of them.

Comment: You need to take the '+' out and replace it with the specific device name your interested in.